# How to refresh IE from command line?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

We have five tv's in our office displaying a local web page written in .net.  This web page can be updated by three managers at any time of the day to tell staff about events.

the problem is the page doesn't refresh - i can go in remotely and hit f5 which wouldn't be a big deal but the page is updated about 4 to 6 times an hour.

what i really want is either a command line script or batch file that refreshes ie and sits on the pc that displays the web page - then i can add a shortcut to it on the managers computers and after they've updated they can click on that.

Is there either a command line to refresh ie or a batch file? or even a command line that fires f5 as a keypress?

Answer (score 2):

How about building in a Refresh to the webpage if it's under your control? E.g. Every minute with
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">`

Comment: I agree.  This is best managed in the Web code, not as a client side hack.  If it were me, I would have updates also update a timestamp somewhere, either a database record or text file or something, have the clients periodically perform an Ajax/xhr call to get the latest timestamp, and if it has changed, refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I'd definitely go autoit:

```
#include <IE.au3>

while (true)
    $oIE = _IEAttach("sample.html", "URL")
    _IEAction($oIE, "refresh")
    Sleep(60 * 1000) ;sleep for an hour
WEnd
```

You can compile the script to a standalone exe too